# Docker Compose extends not overriding configuration

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I recently updated Docker for Mac, now version 3.5.2 (66501), and since then the `extends` functionality in `docker-compose` seems to have stopped working (no idea if that's related though).

I have one big old `docker-compose.yaml` file which is using `extends` quite a bit so I was hoping not having to change that at the moment.

To try I created this dummy `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```yaml
version: '2.1'

services:
    base:
        image: ubuntu:18.04
        command: bash -c "echo 'i am base'"
    
    extender:
        extends:
            service: base
        hostname: extender
        command: bash -c "echo 'i am extender'"
```

When I do `docker compose up` they both echo `i am base`:

```sh
base_1  | i am base
extender_1  | i am base
```

Also if I do `docker compose run extender` it echos `i am base`.

Comment: If you use `docker-compose` (with a hyphen) does it work differently?  `docker compose` (with a space, a `compose` subcommand of `docker`) is pretty new, and this isn't the first SO question where they've behaved differently in out-of-the-mainstream cases.

Comment: Ah yeah I tried using both `docker-compose` and `docker compose`, no difference.
Also I just downgraded to Docker 3.4.0 and it still has the same problem.